# lambdaの使い方を教えてください。

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

下記では上手く実行されるのに

```
df['flag'] = df['current'].apply(lambda x : 1 if x >= 5000 else 0 )
```

下記に変更するとエラーがでます。

```
df['flag'] = df['current'].apply(lambda x : 1 if x >= df['current2'] else 0 )
```

エラーメッセージ

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。

Answer (score 1):

複数の列で`apply`を使用したい場合は、SeriesではなくてDataFrameに対して適用する必要があります。

```
df['flag'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x.current >= x.current2 else 0, axis=1)
```

でも、質問のような計算では、Pandasのベクトル演算を使いましょう。

```
df['flag'] = (df['current'] >= df['current2']).astype(int)
```